# PDFBox 2 Column Issue How To Check Beads

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/PDF/A-8.8.pdf that I'm trying to parse using PDFBox which has 2 columns.  I want the text to be parsed so that the columns are separated, however when I run it through PDFBox it does not separate the 2 columns, rather it concatenates lines from both columns together.

I've read https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-448 which says that some PDF's don't have article/beads that can be used and so the parsing will always be wrong.  I have tried using `stripper.setShouldSeparateByBeads(true)`

How can I check this if it has beads or not?  I haven't found any reading material regarding this concept except for on questions about PDFBox's column parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if beads are in a page with `PDPage.getThreadBeads()`. This will return an empty list if there are no thread beads.

Spoiler alert: your document doesn't have any.

An example on how to use them can be found in the `DrawPrintTextLocations.java` example in the source code download. Examples of PDF files with beads can be found in the files `PDFBOX-3110-003422-p1-beads.pdf` and `PDFBOX-3110-poems-beads.pdf`, also in the source code download.

Bonus tip: have a look at the `ExtractTextByArea.java` example, this should help you extract your PDF file.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me.   I also found that PDFParser's writeString can be overwritten, and inside the function the columns are read as two sets of text.  I could save the text I get there manually and it would work somewhat similar to using PDFTextStripperByArea.  What do you think of this path?  I'm wondering if there's some obvious downside (text could be split when it shouldn't be?).

Comment: I assume you mean PDFStripper, not PDFParser. Yes you can do that... the sequence of texts depends on the PDF, i.e. it doesn't have any "logic", i.e. from left to right, ordered by columns or whatever, it could be anything, so be careful to check that your assumptions are working. If I were you, I'd stay with PDFTextStripperByArea as long as it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!  Mostly I wanted to be able to automatically detect if its 2 or 3 columns, so that's why writeString() would be more useful than manually setting rectangles bounds.